# WinForms Font Dialog Styling is getting Overridden by WPF Application Styles

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

In My WPF application, I am using Font Dialog for setting up font styling to provided text. But while displaying Font Dialog I can see scroll bar styles of Font dialogs are being overwritten by WPF application style.

[image]

Is there a way to customize or remove application styling from Font Dialog.

Below code is written in view model for bringing up font dialog:

```
        var fontDialog = new FontDialog();
        fontDialog.ShowEffects = false;                 
        fontDialog.Font = new Font(textInfo.FontFamily, textInfo.FontSize);

        if (fontDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var selectedFont = fontDialog.Font;
            textInfo.FontSize = (int)selectedFont.Size;
            textInfo.FontFamily = selectedFont.FontFamily.Name;
            textInfo.FontWeight = selectedFont.Bold ? "Bold" : "Regular";
            textInfo.FontStyle = selectedFont.Italic ? "Italic" : "Normal";            
        }
```

Comment: Does your application specify any "Generic" style for ScrollBars. Look for something Unnamed/Keyed Style with TargetType= Scrollbar -- That is what is overriding the style of all scrollbars.

Comment: That is not possible, it is a dialog that is built into the OS and doesn't know anything about WPF.  But what matters a lot is that in a WPF app the visual styles theme is not enabled by default.  You can tell from the appearance of the buttons, that's how they looked 18 years ago.  Better known as the "classic" look.  Something is messing with that look on your machine, that's unlikely to happen on the user's machine.  Enable visual styles to get ahead: Project > Add New Item > select "Application Manifest File".  Remove the XML comments around the "Enable themes" section.

Comment: I tried both the solutions explained above but none of them worked for me.

Comment: `if (fontDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)` <=  Does this compile? Shouldn't it be `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK`. How has the ambiguous reference (`Window.DialogResult`) been resolved to let this run?

Comment: I haven't got any compilation error/warning while executing this code.